# JHipster limit user sessions not working with default JWT configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I've been looking through many similar questions but nothing seems to work. I've added the following to the default Jhispter security configuration:

```
        http
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        SessionRegistry sessionRegistry = new SessionRegistryImpl();
        return sessionRegistry;
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
```

I know Spring Security needs a HttpSessionListener which is added below, and I've seen conflicting reports of whether you need to add a sessionRegistry.

From everything I've read in the spring docs this should be sufficient to limit logins to 1 per user, however you can still login an unlimited amount of times. The Jhispter docs doesn't go into maximum sessions so that isn't much help either.

Here is the entire security configuration:

```
package com.sean.silly.config;

import com.sean.silly.security.*;
import com.sean.silly.security.jwt.*;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter;
import org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
import org.zalando.problem.spring.web.advice.security.SecurityProblemSupport;

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;
    private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;

    public SecurityConfiguration(TokenProvider tokenProvider, CorsFilter corsFilter, SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport) {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
            .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
            .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
        .and()
            .headers()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:")
        .and()
            .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
        .and()
            .featurePolicy("geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; speaker 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; payment 'none'")
        .and()
            .frameOptions()
            .deny()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .and()
            .httpBasic()
        .and()
            .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());
        // @formatter:on

        http
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
    }

    private JWTConfigurer securityConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new JWTConfigurer(tokenProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        SessionRegistry sessionRegistry = new SessionRegistryImpl();
        return sessionRegistry;
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JWT and Sessions (for security/login) are mutually exclusive in jhipster's [security approach](https://www.jhipster.tech/security/) (not to be mixed)

JWT is a stateless authentication mechanism so preventing or disabling multiple logins will require additional work. See similar problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959945/how-to-destroy-jwt-tokens-on-logout/37962259) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881194/allow-one-concurrent-user-per-login-with-jwt)

Configuring the session will not have an effect on that.

Moreover, aside from the JWT issue, your http session configuration is syntactically correct but semantically it doesn't seem to make sense:

`sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)` is saying ["spring will neither create nor use the http session"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.13.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/http/SessionCreationPolicy.html#STATELESS) it's effectively more wrong than the "NEVER" option for your use case.

So then tacking on `maximumSessions(1)` (or anything else) doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't click that the JWT implementation was exclusive to Sessions. The links you have provided me have got what I wanted working!